# Over graphing points

Tags: matlab, random, graph, matlab-figure, distance

I'm trying to randomly create 100 points from 0 - 180, then graph them. Then check the distance between them and if it falls under a certain threshold draw a line between them. I can get the points graphed, and even some lines. But it's not right, some points that are close enough aren't mapped, and some points that are further are mapped.

```
clc; clear all; format compact;
a = [2 3]
b = [16 50]

array = randi(180,100,1);
array2 = randi(180,100,1);
% x = array(:, 1);
% y = array(:,2);
plot(array,array2, '.')
line (a,b)
% radius is 18, which is given k * given d
for j = 1:100
    for i = 1:100
        d = sqrt((array(j)-array(i))^2+(array2(j)-array2(i))^2);
        if d <= 18
           point1 = [array(j), array2(j)];
           point2 = [array(i), array2(i)];
           line( point1, point2)
        end
    end
end
```

**Sample output:**

[image: Sample output]

Comment: There's a typo on the line where you compute distance.

Comment: Caught that, but it still doesn't fix anything sadly

Comment: Did you do `axes equal` after plotting? Maybe distances look different because the scaling of the axes is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the issue now. `line` doesn't draw a line from one point to the next, it draws a line through given x and y coordinates, much like `plot`. Replace this bit:

```
point1 = [array(j), array2(j)];
point2 = [array(i), array2(i)];
line( point1, point2)
```

with this:

```
x = [array(i), array(j)];
y = [array2(i), array2(j)];
line(x, y);
```

or equivalently:

```
line(array([i,j]),array2([i,j]));
```

---

Unsolicited advice:

Use more sensical names than `array` and `array2`. For example `x` and `y`. This bug would have been easy to spot with better names!

Comment: You're the best! That fixed it! Yah, you're right, I should have used more sense names to do it, especially since I was posting it here. Thank you!